# The logical model and the domain model

Tags: database-design, architecture

I've often used the logical model and the domain model interchangeably, but I came across this in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_data_model):

"The term 'Logical Data Model' is sometimes used as a synonym of 'Domain Model' or as an alternative to the domain model. While the two concepts are closely related, and have overlapping goals, a domain model is more focused on capturing the concepts in the problem domain rather than the structure of the data associated with that domain."

Can anyone expound on that? To my mind, the purpose of both was to establish relationships between business objects, and that if we were focusing on the structure of the data, we were getting into the jurisdiction of the physical model.

I typically use a single logical/domain model for two purposes. The first is to establish a starting point for my physical data model. The other is to map out my classes in my business layer.

Is there a better way I should be doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the Wikipedia articles on the [logical model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_data_model) and the [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model).

Based on what I read, the logical model is concerned with modeling the data objects and the relationships between the data objects, without any database considerations.

The domain model is concerned with modeling the processes and the relationships between the processes, without any computer language considerations.

> I typically use a single logical/domain model for two purposes. The first is to establish a starting point for my physical data model. The other is to map out my classes in my business layer.

Your business object classes don't have to match your data model.  As an example, you might have a Person class that on a relational database maps to several different tables; Person, Address, Phone Number, etc.